# which is an abstract class? A question from Oracle exam

Tags: java, uml

[image]

which is an abstract class? A question from Oracle exam

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking what an abstract class is or which one is the abstract class in the given diagram? Here is a link explaning what an abstract class is. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: What a lousy name for an abstract class.

Comment: @tvanfosson - the "lousy" choice of name is deliberate.  The question is testing the candidate's knowledge of UML notation ... not his/her ability to guess if a class is abstract based on its name.

Comment: @stephen - I get it, but in the real world I'd never name a class that way and expect you to differentiate it based only on whether the name is italicized or not.  It annoys me (slightly) that Oracle would offer up a poor example of naming to a student in their training materials since a student might infer that it's entirely reasonable to do this in real code. Clarity and readability of the code is what really matters not the purity of my UML - of course, I hardly write any except on a whiteboard and I'm not fussy about it then.

Comment: @tvanfosson Well there are many business models where you can't trivially distinguish between abstract/concrete classes based on name alone (at least if you don't already know in detail what those classes do or have a special naming convention) - also testing if a candidate is able to guess which class from "Animal", "Dog" and "Horse" is abstract is hardly useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mouse because the name is italicized.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/

Within that url search for specifically for this section:

> Abstract classes and operations
>
> The observant reader will notice that
>   the diagrams in Figures 4 and 5 use
>   italicized text for the BankAccount
>   class name and withdrawal operation.
>   This indicates that the BankAccount
>   class is an abstract class and the
>   withdrawal method is an abstract
>   operation. In other words, the
>   BankAccount class provides the
>   abstract operation signature of
>   withdrawal and the two child classes
>   of CheckingAccount and SavingsAccount
>   each implement their own version of
>   that operation.
>
> However, super classes (parent
>   classes) do not have to be abstract
>   classes. It is normal for a standard
>   class to be a super class.